# Break string into array and pick an element randomly in bash

Tags: arrays, string, bash

The purpose of this is basically create a deck of cards and randomly draw 1. Right now, it's not even breaking up the strings and reading them into the array. I get both a command not found for the `suites` and the `denominations` string and then another error for `RANDOM`.

Am I writing in the IFS line wrong? I'm brand new to bash scripting and I really appreciate everyone's help =]!

```
#!/bin/bash
# Count how many elements.
Suites=“Clubs Diamonds Hearts Spades”
Denominations=“2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Jack Queen King Ace”
# Read into array variable.
IFS=' '
suite=($Suites)
denomination=($Denominations)
# Count how many elements.
num_suites=${#suite[*]}
num_denominations=${#denomination[*]}
echo -n "${denomination[$((RANDOM%num_denominations))]} of "
echo ${suite[$((RANDOM%num_suites))]}
exit 0
```

Comment: This is working for me.  I get no errors, and on a few runs, I see echoed: Queen of Spades; Ace of Clubs; 7 of Hearts.  This is with bash 4.2.24.

Comment: That's weird... how are you running it? I'm using Ubuntu and in the terminal, I type chmod a+rx cards.sh then ./cards.sh to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Count how many elements.
Suites="Clubs Diamonds Hearts Spades"
Denominations="2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Jack Queen King Ace"
# Read into array variable.
IFS=' '
suite=($Suites)
denomination=($Denominations)
# Count how many elements.
num_suites=${#suite[*]}
num_denominations=${#denomination[*]}
echo -n "${denomination[$((RANDOM%num_denominations))]} of "
echo ${suite[$((RANDOM%num_suites))]}
exit 0
```

Here is the script I ran.  The one difference I see is that I use " while you used “ and ” on your Suites and Denomination lines. Or, 0x22 versus u+201c and u+201d.

Comment: *face palm* So it was a typo all along. Must've been the auto correct on the word document that that given. Thank you.